# new MAC protocol employing periodic backoff instead of random one in wireless network

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a new MAC protocol based on 2011 IEEE paper where random waiting time for default MAC wireless networks (802.11 DCF) to a Period-controlled MAC for higher performance.

I will explain the proposed protocol in terms of a simple scenario: consider 2 transmitting nodes experiencing a collision in a network; after they each have waited a random amount of time; say x and y, (implying they both have different backoff periods) if we imply periodic backoff from there on, their backoffs will be x+a, y+a which goes on and will never be equal; preventing them from ever colliding with each other again.

Also, the period of the backoff is same for all the nodes in the network ('a' in the above example), and any change that has to be done with this 'a' period will also affect with all the nodes in the network. This change is based on the channel state and the period is altered following Additive Increase Multiplicative Decrease procedure with respect to the channel idleness threshold set in the protocol algorithm.

Although the author of the above mentioned IEEE paper refused to help with the code, he did mention that the changes he made to implement the protocol were done in the following files :
The code in these files (mac-802.11.cc, mac-timers.cc, mac-802.11.h, mac-timers.h ) is posted in pastebin.ca:

http://pastebin.ca/2303764; http://pastebin.ca/2303763; pastebin.ca/2303762;
pastebin.ca/2303765

Also the algorithm for the proposed MAC protocol is given in : pastebin.ca/2303772

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me alter this method to change the random calculation to periodic.  Thanks.

Any advice or suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER DO THIS KIND OF THINGS

Wireless network are not made by your only devices, and a network protocol is something that is expected to be observed by EVERY device that shares a SAME PHYSICAL LAYER.

What you are doing is essentially improving the performance of your devices by "stoling" to everybody else part of their possibility to access the media.

A new MAC protocol requires necessarily a distinct physical media, hence distinct frequencies and channels, not already in use and assigned for WLAN, otherwise they:

- cannot be certified as 802.11
- can be claimed to be "unauthorized interfering devices", with all the consequences in term of legal issues you may have in all the countries that have regulation about how the EM-spectrum is used. (including the user of such a devices to be imprisoned, in case they will damage whatever public communication!)

When dealing with physical protocols on shared media you cannot do your own rules. And when the shared media is a limited resource (like the air is) public laws and regulations are established.